# What is new(this) mean in Javascript Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

I found this code, to add before and after the ability to run a function, searched and don't know, what is new(self) mean there?

```
Function.prototype.before = function(fn) {
  const self = this
  return function() {
    fn.apply(new(self), arguments)
    return self.apply(new(self), arguments)
  }
}
Function.prototype.after = function(fn) {
  const self = this
  return function() {
    self.apply(new(self), arguments)
    return fn.apply(new(self), arguments)
  }
}


...


const validate = function(){
  // ...
}
const formSubmit = function() {
  // ...
  ajax( 'http:// xxx.com/login', param )
}
submitBtn.onclick = function() {
  formSubmit.before( validate )
}
```

Comment: It means the same as `new self` or `new self()` - and it's *horribly* wrong in that place. Where did you find this code?! It should be `return self.apply(this, arguments)`. Also the return value of the function returned by `after` is wrong.

Comment: Is it node.js or a react frontend? It can't be both. Also this code looks really old, way before ES6…

Comment: And the example usage is also wrong. It needs to be `submitBtn.onclick = formSubmit.before( validate );`, not wrapped in a function expression. (Compare the "normal" `submitBtn.onclick = formSubmit;`).